# What is this medallion?

Tags: hebrew, money, eretz-yisrael, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

This was given to me on my bat mitzvah several years ago, and I have no idea what it's about. Can you please explain/translate what this is? Does it have an official name? I'd like to read more about it.
Thanks.

[image: Gold-colored coin hanging from a necklace. Front shows a Temple-style Menora with olive branches on either side, and the word "ISRAEL"]
[image: [Gold-colored coin hanging from a necklace. Back shows a rose with the Hebrew words "Berucha at l'H biti"]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The front is the [seal of the State of Israel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emblem_of_Israel).

The Hebrew on the back is a verse from Ruth ([Ruth 3:10](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2903.htm#10)) which means "You are blessed to G-d, my daughter" which were words that [Boaz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boaz) said to [Ruth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruth_%28biblical_figure%29) when she asked him to marry her.

It doesn't have an official name; it is a thoughtful trinket.

Comment: The text around the edge of the back is an English translation of the Hebrew text in the middle.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much! So it's not really typical to give this type of medallion pendant for bat mitzvahs, it's just a thoughtful trinket, right? Thanks again +1

Comment: Necklaces aren't an uncommon bat-mitzvah gift, though often they have a *magen david* (star of David) or a *chai* (the word "life").  This is more unusual, but doesn't seem out of place.  As YEZ said, it's a thoughtful gift.

Comment: Trinket may not be appropriate. It may well be issued by the Israel Coins and Medals Corporation. You would have to consult an expert to assess its value as a collectable.

Comment: I have checked http://israelmint.com/?section=449&product=4352&lineItem=2905 - if it is gold it seems to be priced at NIS 1968, although the version in the photo does not have a pendant pearl attached. It does seem to be an official issue though.

Comment: @Epicentre Happens to be I was using trinket to just mean a small piece of jewelry (which is one definition), but unless my color scheme, resolution, and eye-glasses are all skewed, that item in the image is obviously not gold.

Comment: @YEZ - I agree, it doesn't look gold, but online photos are notoriously poor at colour accuracy. All it needs is overcompression...